# Why there are negative values coming up when I create a random array - "np.random.rand"

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Why there is negative numbers when I create the below array?

```
a12 = np.random.randn(3, 5)
a12
```

Output:-

```
array([[-1.43586215,  1.16316375,  0.01023306, -0.98150865,  0.46210347],
       [ 0.1990597 , -0.60021688,  0.06980208, -0.3853136 ,  0.11351735],
       [ 0.66213067,  1.58601682, -1.2378155 ,  2.13303337, -1.9520878 ]])
```

Comment: Randn samples from a normal distribution (which can have positive or negative values. You can read more about it on the numpy documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html

Comment: Your question title is about `np.random.rand` but your code is `np.random.randn`. They are two different samplings.

Comment: Sorry Quang Hoang.. I have corrected it now.. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

np.random.randn() draws a sample from the Standard Normal Distribution i.e N(0,1). Passing in the dimensions returns an array of the given shape i.e np.random.randn(3,5) will return an array with shape (3,5) with all elements drawn from the standard normal distribution. Hence, we can get negative numbers, and infact all numbers in R.[image]